# Blackberry 8300 simulator stopped working. It shows a jvm error 545?

Tags: blackberry

Blackberry 8300 simulator crashed.
It shows a jvm error 545.
Any idea how to fix it up??
Or I need to install the simulator again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't need to reinstall, assuming you had a good install in the first place and the issue arose during a test run.

Running clean.bat (should be in the simulator directory) will clean up and reset the simulator back to its initial state.

Comment: Perfect its working!! Thanks
But can you tell me how do I clean up my simulator.
It doesn't delete the applications which I installed on the simulator.

Comment: For me clean.bat always removes apps under dev test, so I'm not sure.  There is a thread that may have a clue for you here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-do-I-remove-applications-from-simulator/m-p/40050;jsessionid=79B464349859909EE4D45A6369557377

Comment: As an option, that sometimes works. Just delete all *.dmp files from your simulator folder. It will preserve all installed custom apps in the simulator filesystem, but will remove all data saved by these applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your application on eclipse, browse to

```
Eclipse_Folder\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\simulator
```

and delete all `.debug` files and `.dmp` files.

restart your eclipse.